# how to best implement a "fetch-and-set" in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, atomic

What's best practice for implementing a fetch-and-set in java when your focus is on performance?

Let's say I have a queue tail `tail`, somewhere.
And my own node enqueues itself by replacing the tail with itself, storing the predecessor in a field `pred`.

Currently, I can only think of something like this:

```
public class MyQueue{
    public static class Node{public Node pred = null;}

    public Node tail = new Node(); //sentinel node
}
```

And then something like ...

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

public class MyClass{
    private static long tailOffset = 0;
    public MyClass{
        //ideally, tailOffset can be hardcoded at compile time s.t. this is obsolete
       if(tailOffset <= 0){
           this.tailOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(MyQueue.class.getDeclaredField("tail");
       }
    }

    MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();

    public void createAndInsertNode(){
         Node node = new Node();
         synchronized(node){
             Node pred = queue.tail;
             while(!unsafe.compareAndSwapObject(queue,tailOffset,pred,node)){
                 pred = queue.tail;
             }
             node.pred = pred;
         }
    }

    public static final Unsafe unsafe;
    static {
        try {
            Constructor<Unsafe> unsafeConstructor = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
            unsafeConstructor.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = unsafeConstructor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

(Haven't tested the code, but it should get the idea across.)

I really don't like using `synchronized`, here, because it demands I put all accesses to `node.pred` into a `synchronized(node)` block as well.

Basically, all I want is

```
public void createAndInsertNode(){
     Node node = new Node();
     node.pred = FetchAndSet(queue.tail,node);
}
```

Where that entire statement second line is atomic.
Is there something that would allow this?

Comment: The obvious answer is "there is no best way unless you know what your data is going to be so you can take advantage of whatever properties you *know* it will always exhibit". A generalised solution will almost by definition be less efficient. If you genuinely care about performance, you want to tailor your data structure to your data. Also, what do you count as performance? Does memory footprint factor in? What's acceptable store vs. fetch tradeoff? (which can be slower than the other?) Are you optimizing the average runtime (what is average?) or driving down the runtime upper bound? etc. etc.

Comment: What's wrong with [`AtomicReference.getAndSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `Unsafe` directly for such a task.

One solution to avoid synchronized blocks is to use atomic references. It will end up using the same CAS instructions that you intended to use.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MyQueue {
  public static class Node {
    public Node pred = null;
  }

  public final AtomicReference<Node> tail = new AtomicReference<>(new Node());

  public void insertNewNode() {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.pred = tail.getAndSet(node);
  }
}
```